# Pass Component as Template Variable

Tags: templates, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a generic method that will remove duplicate Components from a GameObject.

I get the following compile error. How can I fix this?

```
The type `T' must be convertible to `UnityEngine.Component' in order to use it as parameter `T' in the generic type or method
```

Heres my code:

```
public static bool removeDuplicateComponents<T>(GameObject go) {

    bool hasComponent  = false;
    bool hasDuplicates = false;

    foreach (T c in go.GetComponents<T>()) {  // error line
        if (!hasComponent) {
            hasComponent = true;
            continue;
        }

        Destroy(c);
        hasDuplicates = true;
    }

    return hasDuplicates;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by adding `where T : Component` to the function declaration.

```
public static bool removeDuplicateComponents<T>(GameObject go) where T : Component {

    bool hasComponent  = false;
    bool hasDuplicates = false;

    foreach (T c in go.GetComponents<T>()) {  // error line
        if (!hasComponent) {
            hasComponent = true;
            continue;
        }

        Destroy(c);
        hasDuplicates = true;
    }

    return hasDuplicates;
}
```